# How do I express, algebraically, this comparison of two sets of sets?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Say I have two sets ($A$ and $B$) containing three sets of the same integers. For example:

$A_1 = \left\{{1,2}\right\}$,
$A_2 = \left\{{3}\right\}$,
$A_3 = \left\{{4,5,6}\right\}$

$B_1 = \left\{{1,3,5}\right\}$,
$B_2 = \left\{{4}\right\}$,
$B_3 = \left\{{2,6}\right\}$

I have a procedure that compares the two sets of sets to get a factor relating to their similarity like this:

$$\frac{n(A_1\cap B_1) + n(A_2\cap B_2) + n(A_3\cap B_3)}{n(A_1+A_2+A_3)} = \frac{2}{6}$$

$$\frac{n(A_1\cap B_1) + n(A_3\cap B_2) + n(A_3\cap B_3)}{n(A_2+A_2+A_3)} = \frac{2}{6}$$

$$\frac{n(A_2\cap B_1) + n(A_3\cap B_2) + n(A_1\cap B_3)}{n(A_1+A_2+A_3)} = \frac{3}{6}$$

$$\frac{n(A_2\cap B_1) + n(A_1\cap B_2) + n(A_3\cap B_3)}{n(A_1+A_2+A_3)} = \frac{2}{6}$$

$$\frac{n(A_3\cap B_1) + n(A_1\cap B_2) + n(A_2\cap B_3)}{n(A_1+A_2+A_3)} = \frac{1}{6}$$

$$\frac{n(A_3\cap B_1) + n(A_2\cap B_2) + n(A_1\cap B_3)}{n(A_1+A_2+A_3)} = \frac{2}{6}$$

In the numerator, I am looking at all 6 possible permutations of $A$ and comparing them to $B$. I then pick the largest result ($\frac{3}{6}$ in the example).

**What is the most concise way to show this algebraically?**

Comment: in the denominator, you mean $n(A \cup B \cup C)$?

Comment: @GA316 I mean the combined length of $A_1$, $A_2$ and $A_3$ (=6). I'm not sure of the correct representation at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression you're looking for is one of: $$\mathop{\mathrm{max}}_{f:\mathbf{Perm}(J)}\frac{\sum_{j:J}|A_j\cap B_{f(j)}|}{\sum_{j:J}|A_j|}, \qquad \mathop{\mathrm{max}}_{f:\mathbf{Perm}(J)}\frac{\sum_{j:J}|A_j\cap B_{f(j)}|}{\left|\bigcup_{j:J}A_j\right|}$$

depending on what you mean. In fact, we can pull out the denominator, since it doesn't depend on $f$:

$$\frac{1}{\sum_{j:J}|A_j|}\left[\mathop{\mathrm{max}}_{f:\mathbf{Perm}(J)} \sum_{j:J}|A_j\cap B_{f(j)}|\right], \qquad \frac{1}{\left|\bigcup_{j:J}A_j\right|}\left[\mathop{\mathrm{max}}_{f:\mathbf{Perm}(J)}\sum_{j:J}|A_j\cap B_{f(j)}|\right]$$

This latter form is both more theoretically useful, and also faster to compute.

Comment: Thanks @goblin. I think I want $\sum_{j:J}|A_j|$ as the denominator. Is the ambiguity in my question related to the $+$ symbols in the denominators of the example?

Comment: @atomh33ls, no worries. Yeah, that's where I'm unsure of your meaning. By $n(A_1+A_2+A_3)$, do you mean $|A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3|$, or do you mean $|A_1|+|A_2|+|A_3|$? If they're disjoint, these numbers agree, of course.

Comment: I meant $|A1|+|A2|+|A3|$. But, yes, the sets are disjoint. Also, as there always be 3 subsets, I will probably choose to represent $J$ as $3$.